# Interpret hazard ratio < 1

Tags: hazard

In my book the example for interpreting a hazard ratio < 1 includes just a single example with a hazard ratio of 0.5. It is very confusing. If you have a hazard ratio of 0.2, does that mean the risk of hazard is reduced by (0.2) 20% or (1-.8) 80%?

Answer (score 1):

It is a *ratio*, so a hazard ratio of 0.2 means a relative reduction of 80%.